# UI5 - Unable to Bind JSONModel with XML view

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I'm trying to use a external JSON file to bind data into a XML View in SAP WebIDE. And here is the code I'm using

view1.xml

```
 <mvc:View controllerName="com.db.DataBinding.controller.View1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <App id="idAppControl">
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <m:Table id="tab1" items="{path : '/ProductCollection'}">
                        <columns>
                            <m:Column width="auto">
                                <m:Label text="Product Id"/>
                            </m:Column>
                            <m:Column width="auto">
                                <m:Label text="Product Name"/>
                            </m:Column>
                            <m:Column width="auto">
                                <m:Label text="Category"/>
                            </m:Column>
                            <m:Column width="auto">
                                <m:Label text="Supplier"/>
                            </m:Column>
                        </columns>
                        <m:ColumnListItem>
                            <m:Text text="{ProductId}"/>
                            <m:Text text="{Name}"/>
                            <m:Text text="{Category}"/>
                            <m:Text text="{SupplierName}"/>
                        </m:ColumnListItem>
                    </m:Table>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

view1.controller

```
onInit: function () {
        var oTable = this.getView().byId("tab1");
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData("./products.json");
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
    }
```

manifest.json

```
{
"_version": "1.8.0",
"sap.app": {
    "id": "com.db.DataBinding",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "sourceTemplate": {
        "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
        "version": "1.40.12"
    }
},
"sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": ["sap_hcb", "sap_belize"]
},
"sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "com.db.DataBinding.view.View1",
        "type": "XML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.layout": {},
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {}
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "com.db.DataBinding.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": {
        "css": [{
            "uri": "css/style.css"
        }]
    },
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "viewPath": "com.db.DataBinding.view",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "controlId": "idAppControl",
            "clearControlAggregation": false
        },
        "routes": [{
            "name": "RouteView1",
            "pattern": "RouteView1",
            "target": ["TargetView1"]
        }],
        "targets": {
            "TargetView1": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewName": "View1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>DataBinding</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.db.DataBinding": "./"}'>
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            new sap.m.Shell({
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height : "100%",
                    name : "com.db.DataBinding"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
```

products.json

```
{
"ProductCollection": [
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1000",
        "Category": "Laptops",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Notebook Basic 15 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 15\" LCD, 4 GB DDR3 RAM, 500 GB Hard Disc, Windows 8 Pro",
        "Name": "Notebook Basic 15",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-03-26",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1000.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 10,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 956,
        "Width": 30,
        "Depth": 18,
        "Height": 3,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1001",
        "Category": "Laptops",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.5,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Notebook Basic 17 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 17\" LCD, 4 GB DDR3 RAM, 500 GB Hard Disc, Windows 8 Pro",
        "Name": "Notebook Basic 17",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-04-17",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1001.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 20,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 1249,
        "Width": 29,
        "Depth": 17,
        "Height": 3.1,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1002",
        "Category": "Laptops",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Notebook Basic 18 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 18\" LCD, 8 GB DDR3 RAM, 1000 GB Hard Disc, Windows 8 Pro",
        "Name": "Notebook Basic 18",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-01-07",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1002.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 10,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 1570,
        "Width": 28,
        "Depth": 19,
        "Height": 2.5,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1003",
        "Category": "Laptops",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Smartcards",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Notebook Basic 19 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 19\" LCD, 8 GB DDR3 RAM, 1000 GB Hard Disc, Windows 8 Pro",
        "Name": "Notebook Basic 19",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-04-09",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1003.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 15,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 1650,
        "Width": 32,
        "Depth": 21,
        "Height": 4,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1007",
        "Category": "Accessories",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "WeightMeasure": 0.2,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Digital Organizer with State-of-the-Art Storage Encryption",
        "Name": "ITelO Vault",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-05-17",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1007.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 15,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 299,
        "Width": 32,
        "Depth": 22,
        "Height": 3,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1010",
        "Category": "Accessories",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.3,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Notebook Professional 15 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 15\" Multitouch LCD, 8 GB DDR3 RAM, 500 GB SSD - DVD-Writer (DVD-R/+R/-RW/-RAM),Windows 8 Pro",
        "Name": "Notebook Professional 15",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-02-22",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1010.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 16,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 1999,
        "Width": 33,
        "Depth": 20,
        "Height": 3,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1011",
        "Category": "Laptops",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.1,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Notebook Professional 17 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 17\" Multitouch LCD, 8 GB DDR3 RAM, 500 GB SSD - DVD-Writer (DVD-R/+R/-RW/-RAM),Windows 8 Pro",
        "Name": "Notebook Professional 17",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-01-02",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1011.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 17,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 2299,
        "Width": 33,
        "Depth": 23,
        "Height": 2,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1020",
        "Category": "Accessories",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "WeightMeasure": 0.16,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Digital Organizer with State-of-the-Art Encryption for Storage and Network Communications",
        "Name": "ITelO Vault Net",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-05-08",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1020.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 14,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 459,
        "Width": 10,
        "Depth": 1.8,
        "Height": 17,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1021",
        "Category": "Accessories",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "WeightMeasure": 0.18,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Digital Organizer with State-of-the-Art Encryption for Storage and Secure Stellite Link",
        "Name": "ITelO Vault SAT",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-06-30",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1021.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 50,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 149,
        "Width": 11,
        "Depth": 1.7,
        "Height": 18,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1022",
        "Category": "Accessories",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "WeightMeasure": 0.2,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "32 GB Digital Assistant with high-resolution color screen",
        "Name": "Comfort Easy",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-03-02",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1022.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 30,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 1679,
        "Width": 84,
        "Depth": 1.5,
        "Height": 14,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1023",
        "Category": "Accessories",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Technocom",
        "WeightMeasure": 0.8,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "64 GB Digital Assistant with high-resolution color screen and synthesized voice output",
        "Name": "Comfort Senior",
        "DateOfSale": "2017-02-25",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1023.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 24,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 512,
        "Width": 80,
        "Depth": 1.6,
        "Height": 13,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1030",
        "Category": "Flat Screen Monitors",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 21,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Optimum Hi-Resolution max. 1920 x 1080 @ 85Hz, Dot Pitch: 0.27mm",
        "Name": "Ergo Screen E-I",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1030.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 14,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 230,
        "Width": 37,
        "Depth": 12,
        "Height": 36,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1031",
        "Category": "Flat Screen Monitors",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 21,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Optimum Hi-Resolution max. 1920 x 1200 @ 85Hz, Dot Pitch: 0.26mm",
        "Name": "Ergo Screen E-II",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1031.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 24,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 285,
        "Width": 40.8,
        "Depth": 19,
        "Height": 43,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1032",
        "Category": "Flat Screen Monitors",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 21,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Optimum Hi-Resolution max. 2560 x 1440 @ 85Hz, Dot Pitch: 0.25mm",
        "Name": "Ergo Screen E-III",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1032.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 50,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 345,
        "Width": 40.8,
        "Depth": 19,
        "Height": 43,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1035",
        "Category": "Flat Screen Monitors",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 14,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Optimum Hi-Resolution max. 1600 x 1200 @ 85Hz, Dot Pitch: 0.24mm",
        "Name": "Flat Basic",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1035.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 23,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 399,
        "Width": 39,
        "Depth": 20,
        "Height": 41,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1036",
        "Category": "Flat Screen Monitors",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 15,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Optimum Hi-Resolution max. 2048 x 1080 @ 85Hz, Dot Pitch: 0.26mm",
        "Name": "Flat Future",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1036.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 22,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 430,
        "Width": 45,
        "Depth": 26,
        "Height": 46,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1037",
        "Category": "Flat Screen Monitors",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
        "WeightMeasure": 17,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Optimum Hi-Resolution max. 2016 x 1512 @ 85Hz, Dot Pitch: 0.24mm",
        "Name": "Flat XL",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1037.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 23,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 1230,
        "Width": 54.5,
        "Depth": 22.1,
        "Height": 39.1,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1040",
        "Category": "Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Alpha Printers",
        "WeightMeasure": 32,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Print 2400 dpi image quality color documents at speeds of up to 32 ppm (color) or 36 ppm (monochrome), letter/A4. Powerful 500 MHz processor, 512MB of memory",
        "Name": "Laser Professional Eco",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1040.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 21,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 830,
        "Width": 51,
        "Depth": 46,
        "Height": 30,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1041",
        "Category": "Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Alpha Printers",
        "WeightMeasure": 23,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Up to 22 ppm color or 24 ppm monochrome A4/letter, powerful 500 MHz processor and 128MB of memory",
        "Name": "Laser Basic",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1041.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 8,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 490,
        "Width": 48,
        "Depth": 42,
        "Height": 26,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1042",
        "Category": "Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Alpha Printers",
        "WeightMeasure": 17,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Print up to 25 ppm letter and 24 ppm A4 color or monochrome, with Available first-page-out-time of less than 13 seconds for monochrome and less than 15 seconds for color",
        "Name": "Laser Allround",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1042.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 9,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 349,
        "Width": 53,
        "Depth": 50,
        "Height": 65,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1050",
        "Category": "Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Alpha Printers",
        "WeightMeasure": 3,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "4800 dpi x 1200 dpi - up to 35 ppm (mono) / up to 34 ppm (color) - capacity: 250 sheets - Hi-Speed USB, Ethernet",
        "Name": "Ultra Jet Super Color",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1050.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 17,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 139,
        "Width": 41,
        "Depth": 41,
        "Height": 28,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1051",
        "Category": "Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Printer for All",
        "WeightMeasure": 1.9,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "1000 dpi x 1000 dpi - up to 35 ppm (mono) / up to 34 ppm (color) - capacity: 250 sheets - Hi-Speed USB - excellent dimensions for the small office",
        "Name": "Ultra Jet Mobile",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1051.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 18,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 99,
        "Width": 46,
        "Depth": 32,
        "Height": 25,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1052",
        "Category": "Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Printer for All",
        "WeightMeasure": 18,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "4800 dpi x 1200 dpi - up to 35 ppm (mono) / up to 34 ppm (color) - capacity: 250 sheets - Hi-Speed USB2.0, Ethernet",
        "Name": "Ultra Jet Super Highspeed",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1052.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 25,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 170,
        "Width": 41,
        "Depth": 41,
        "Height": 28,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1055",
        "Category": "Multifunction Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Printer for All",
        "WeightMeasure": 6.3,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "1000 dpi x 1000 dpi - up to 16 ppm (mono) / up to 15 ppm (color)- capacity 80 sheets - scanner (216 x 297 mm, 1200dpi x 2400dpi)",
        "Name": "Multi Print",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1055.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 16,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 99,
        "Width": 55,
        "Depth": 45,
        "Height": 29,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1056",
        "Category": "Multifunction Printers",
        "MainCategory": "Printers & Scanners",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Printer for All",
        "WeightMeasure": 4.3,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "1200 dpi x 1200 dpi - up to 25 ppm (mono) / up to 24 ppm (color)- capacity 80 sheets - scanner (216 x 297 mm, 2400dpi x 4800dpi, high resolution)",
        "Name": "Multi Color",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1056.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 5,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 119,
        "Width": 51,
        "Depth": 41.3,
        "Height": 22,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    },
    {
        "ProductId": "HT-1060",
        "Category": "Mice",
        "MainCategory": "Computer Components",
        "TaxTarifCode": "1",
        "SupplierName": "Oxynum",
        "WeightMeasure": 0.09,
        "WeightUnit": "KG",
        "Description": "Cordless Optical USB Mice, Laptop, Color: Black, Plug&Play",
        "Name": "Cordless Mouse",
        "ProductPicUrl": "test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1060.jpg",
        "Status": "Available",
        "Quantity": 25,
        "UoM": "PC",
        "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
        "Price": 9,
        "Width": 6,
        "Depth": 14.5,
        "Height": 3.5,
        "DimUnit": "cm"
    }]}
```

this is the code I've been using and when I execute it I get this error :

**SCRIPT5022: failed to load 'null/App.js' from ../../resources/null/App.js: 404 - Not Found

HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://webidetesting4688865-p2000413989trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/resources/null/App.js**

and I get a blank screen

could you please tell me what's wrong with the code??

PS: Please Comment if you feel the information provided us inadequate

Comment: The first five 404 requests are normal - UI5 is trying to load the appropriate translatable texts for your language / locale. The last one is strange though due to the fact that it seems to have a problem with your paths (and makes this request to the "null" url). Can you please show us the index.html (if any) and the manifest.json?

Comment: added manifest.json and index.html

Comment: provice structure of products.json, make sure the model data is avaiable in the view

Comment: uploaded products.json

Answer (score 0):

Remove `products>` from the binding on the table, since `setModel` doesn’t use a name for the model either.

Then it should work. (Assuming the url is correct and the json file is wellformattted)

If you create the model in onInit, you don’t need it in Manifest. Once you get it working, you should define it in Manifest, not in `onInit`

Comment: Thank you for your help.....   removed products> from view.xml and removed entry from manifest. the first error : "SCRIPT5022" is gone but the second remains. Please help